# Error converting wav to caf for the iPhone using afconvert

Tags: iphone, audio, wav, afconvert

Here's the command I'm typing in a Terminal window:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 buzzer.wav buzzer.caf
Error: ExtAudioFileOpenURL failed ('dta?')
```

Notice that buzzer.wav is my sound file.

What's wrong? How should I do the conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all wave (.wav) files are alike. Some are actually some unrecognized file format. What fixed it for me was to open the file in Audacity and then export the sound in wave format; then use afconvert.

Comment: Same here: open wav and export as wav!